# How to return websocket message in functions?

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-modules

I'm trying to make a function that returns incoming information from a WebSocket server.
I want that it looks something like this in the main file when it's finished:

```
const getMessage = require('./getMessage.js');

let message = getMessage();
console.log(message);
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to return the incoming messages from the event listener

```
websocket.on('message', function incoming(reply) {

});
```

My getMessage.js file looks like this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');

module.exports = function getMessage() {
  let msg;
  ws.on('message', function incoming(reply) {
    msg = reply;
  });
  return msg;
}
```

But instead of returning the incoming message, it returns undefined. How can I get the incoming message of my Websocket server in one function?

Current code of index.js:

```
const api = require('./api.js');

let message = api();
console.log(messag);
```

Current code of api.js:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');

let api = (function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return msg;
});

    ws.on('message', function msg(reply) {
        api(reply);
    });
```

If I run the program it logs:

> undefined
> undefined
> Hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function like `api` to get the message from a websocket. Websockets are inherently async, so your `incoming()` should be calling another function, or setting variables.

Maybe try adding a callback function that can receive the message.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');

module.exports = function api(onMessageReceived) {
    if (typeof onMessageReceived !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('onMessageReceived must be a callback function');
    }

    ws.on('message', function(reply){
        onMessageReceived(reply);
    });
};
```

**EDIT:**

You don't want to wrap your `api` function in parentheses, and don't need it to be a variable. Try something more like:

```js
function api(msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    // "return"ing a value doesn't do anything, it is unneeded. 
}

ws.on('message', function msg(reply) {
    if (reply) {
        api(reply);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. The error gets thrown every time

Comment: What do you mean? I tried exactly the code you suggested.

Comment: When you call your `api()`, you need to pass it a callback function, like this: `api(function(msg) {console.log(msg);})` or better yet `api(myCallbackFunction)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is only one new Problem. Now the program logs two times. The first time the script logs undefined the second time it logs the message. When I return the value it only returns undefined.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. It would be a lot more helpful if you could show your current code.